# Azure Resource Created by not available

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Team

I have 100's of subscriptions used by 100+ people. There are resources created 2 yrs back. i want to clean up my subscription. Is there any way i can know who created that resource? i tried activity logs and all but of no use it has only limited period data. Pls help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That info is gone. If you care about this data, you should persist your Azure audit logs (default is 3 months)

Comment: any alternative. cos who created is a basic info while managing such a huge portfolio will be difficult.